# Object Arrays Error cannot find symbol

Tags: java, arrays

so I had this java code below which the compiler said couldn't find symbol for my car class so had to create an empty class like this:

```
public class TrafficQueue {
private Car [] carArray;
private int numberOfcarsInQueue;


public TrafficQueue(int numberOfcarsInQueue){
carArray = new Car[numberOfcarsInQueue];


}
private class Car {} ; // define an empty Car class


public void add(Car car){
carArray[numberOfcarsInQueue] = car;
numberOfcarsInQueue ++;

}

public static void main(String[] args) {
        // TODO code application logic here


         TrafficQueue queueLane1 = new TrafficQueue(10);
        queueLane1.add("Red Chevrolet");
```

i try to run and i get an error using queuelane1.add("Red Chevrolet")

from my previous knowledge of creating object arrays this is done as:

```
private Car [] carArray;
```

then initialised in the constructor as:

```
carArray = new Car[numberOfcarsInQueue];
```

but however this does not work until i create a new empty class.
my question why do i have to create a new class?

and from my code how i do i add a new car object?

Comment: If you don't create a `Car` class, what type do you think the compiler should make your array?

Comment: `queueLane1.add("Red Chevrolet");` is adding a `String`, not a `Car`...

Comment: well been reading some text and none of them seem to create but somehow their code works. check this link pls http://www-scf.usc.edu/~csci455/curr/bigJava/ch16/section_3_4/CircularArrayQueue.java

Comment: i have just read through a previous similar post which explains why this error occurs but unfortunately does not explain much further using a class...